Why when I use the DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync() method on mobile devices output does not exists?
Why when I use the DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync() method from the expo-document-picker library on mobile devices does it not return the list of files, output?
My project is built in react native web and I'm trying to send a file to the server, when I use the mentioned method on mobile devices the output values ​​don't appear, this is my current code:
Here the state that will receive the file is declared:
    const [certificateFile, setCertificateFile] = useState<null | File>(null)


Here is the function that will set this state declared:
const pickDocument = async () => {
        try {
            const file = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
                type: "application/pkcs12",
            })

            if (file.output && file.output[0].type == "application/pkcs12") {
                setCertificateFile(file.output[0])
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

And here the form submission function is declared:
async onSubmit(values, formikHelpers) {
            if (loading) return
            if (!certificateFile) {
                formik.setFieldError("certificate_file", "Obrigatório o envio do certificado digital.")
                return
            }
            setLoading(true)
            const formData = new FormData()

            const data: CustomerForm = {
                ...values,
            }
            formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(data))
            formData.append("certificate_file", certificateFile)
            try {
                const response = await api.post("/customer", formData)

                console.log(response)
                onDismiss()
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            } finally {
                setLoading(false)
            }
        },


Consulting the documentation I realized that the output option is only available for the web,
enter image description here

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
